# Unable to get dblink to work on read replica

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

We have 2 databases on AWS RDS, *OMS* and *SFMS*, with each database having its own read replica. We use **dblink** in *SFMS* to fetch data of Table A from *OMS*. It works perfectly on my SFMS db instance with *Master* role, but get an `ERROR: could not establish connection` on our read replica DB.

Here is how I have setup the dblink:

`SELECT * FROM dblink(
       'dbname=<DB End Point> user=<username> password=<password>', 
       'SELECT id, <Other fields> from A') AS oms_A
(id int, <Remaining Schema>)`

I can always create a materialized view on *SFMS* to get it to work. Is their some mistake that I am making while setting up DBLink to use it on a read replica instance?

Comment: check logs in replica for errors?..

Comment: `2017-10-10 10:50:50 UTC:static-tataidc.co.in(50130):postgres@sfms_production:[19804]:ERROR: could not establish connection
2017-10-10 10:50:50 UTC:static-tataidc.co.in(50130):postgres@sfms_production:[19804]:DETAIL: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host <OMS Hostname> (<Host IP>) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
`
but I am able to successfully run it on my master RDS instance.

Comment: there's no DETAIL line?.. please try smae in psql (not sure which client you use) - aha - timed out. now makes sense

Comment: check security groups then?..

Answer (score -1):

This works on Aiven's PostgreSQL service. Please checkout aiven.io.

To set it up you first need to create the extension on the master server with 'CREATE EXTENSION dblink;'

The foreign server definitions and user name mappings also have to be created on the master which will then replicate them to the read-only replicas.

Once those are setup you can do things like:  SELECT dblink_connect('myconn', 'db2remote'); and SELECT * FROM dblink('myconn','SELECT * FROM foo') AS t(id int); on the read-replica.

Hope this helps.